# Rotating IP on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have one instance on Google Cloud Compute engine. By default, it has 1 ephemeral external IP address.

I need to constantly change this external IP, ideally every 1-2 minute.

Is there any way to make this "IP rotation" by running some code? 
Also, once new IP assigned, is there any way to get this IP by the code from the previous question and save it in external DB?

Update: Use case is to provide back-connect IP proxy server with IP rotation

Comment: May I ask?  What is the value/function of changing the external IP address every couple of minutes?  I'm not seeing any great reason or value in changing it and I'm hoping you can set me straight.

Comment: Please provide us "use case" for same & why it is needed.

Comment: Use case is to provide back-connect IP proxy server with IP rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely can be accomplished with `add-access-config`. As the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-access-config) reads:

> `gcloud compute instances add-access-config` is used to create access configurations for network interfaces of Google Compute Engine virtual machines. This allows you to assign a public, external IP to a virtual machine.

This lists external IP addresses (and indicates if they're currently assigned):

```
gcloud compute addresses list | grep external
```

Adding all IP adresses to a NIC and then rotating the address of a service might be less disruptive.